# Adding HTML code using for loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add li elements in a html codes to a div element, following is my html code:

**Place where the elements to be added:**

```
<div class="form-body" id="nitspopupmenu"></div>
```

**Elements of ul:**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nitsmenu" data-nitspagelabel="1">
        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#navigation">Home</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#ourteam">Our Team</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My Jquery code:**

```
$(e).fadeIn(400);

$('#nitspagesorter').fadeIn(400).css({
    'top': mouseY,
    'left': mouseX
}).draggable();

$('#nitsmenubutton').hide();

var licount = $("#nitsmenu li").length;
for (i = 0; i < licount; i++) {
    var lielem = $("#nitsmenu li").text();
    var element = $(lielem).text();
    $("#nitspopupmenu").html("<div class='form-group'><div class='pagesmenu selected'><span><i class ='fa fa-bars'></i>" + lielem + "");
}
```

I'm poping up the content to popup box, I'm getting the `li` name properly but its showing only the last element i.e. Contact, 
`$("#nitspopupmenu").html("<div class='form-group'><div class='pagesmenu selected'><span><i class ='fa fa-bars'></i>" + lielem + "");` is executing at last or might be replacing the content everytime and showing the last result

Please help

Comment: You overwriting the HTML of `#nitspopupmenu` on every iteration of the loop, hence only the last one is visible. I'm not sure what behaviour you're expecting to know what needs to be changed.

Comment: thats true its getting overwritten, it should add html everytime with the value of element, as I want to display all the elements. How can we overcome this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should use `append()` over `html()`

```
for (i = 0; i < licount; i++) {
    var lielem = $("#nitsmenu li").text();
    var element = $(lielem).text();
    $("#nitspopupmenu").append("<div class='form-group'><div class='pagesmenu selected'><span><i class ='fa fa-bars'></i>" + lielem + "");
}
```

You should put all string with in one line, if multiple lines required then concat with + sign

Answer (score 5):

`.html()` **replaces** the content of the element, use `.append()` to add to it.

---

You also need to write valid HTML. You have three start tags that are missing their end tags there.

Comment: .append dosen't accepts span tags. I mean I was having problem with span tag while executing this, even i tried wrapinner too.

Comment: Span elements do not cause a problem with append: http://jsbin.com/qavuhor/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for the `.append()` instruction. Using the `.html()`instruction will always delete all the content inside the element you have chosen. Using the `.append()` instruction appends the specified content at the end.